# React, Redux: Adding middleware causes type error every time dispatch() is called

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I've added [LogRocket middleware](https://docs.logrocket.com/reference/redux-logging) to my redux store and now every time thunkAPI.dispatch() is called, I see this error:

> Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<any, any, {}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.

If I remove the new middleware, it works perfectly, but I know it's not an issue with the middleware but with my typescript configuration. Many thanks in advance!

Code snippets are below. In this example, I would receive two errors, one for each thunkAPI.dispatch() call in mySlice.tsx.

#### store.ts

```
import { Action } from 'redux'
import thunkMiddleware, { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk'
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import mySlice from './mySlice'
import LogRocket from 'logrocket'

const configurePortalStore = (preloadedState?: any) => {
  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
      mySlice: mySlice,
    },
    preloadedState,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
      getDefaultMiddleware({
        serializableCheck: {
          ignoredActions: ['myAction'],
          ignoredActionPaths: ['meta.arg', 'payload.meta.arg'],
          ignoreState: true,
        },
      }).concat(thunkMiddleware, LogRocket.reduxMiddleware()),
  })
  return store
}

export const store = configurePortalStore()

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
>
```

#### mySlice.tsx

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { AppDispatch } from './store'

export const api = () => axios.create({
  baseURL: "myURL",
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {
    Authorization: "myToken",
  },
});

export const myPostRequest = createAsyncThunk<
  any,
  any,
  { dispatch: AppDispatch }
>("mySlice/myPostRequest", async (payload, thunkAPI) => {
  return api()
    .post("/myRequest", payload)
    .then((res) => res.data)
    .then((data) => {
      return data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error.response.data.tokenExpired) {
        thunkAPI.dispatch(
          myRefreshTokenFunc(() => // This function updates the token and retries the function passed into it
            thunkAPI.dispatch(myPostRequest(payload))
          )
        );
      }
      return error.response.data;
    });
});
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es6",
      "es2021",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "outDir": "build",
  "sourceMap": true
}
```

Comment: If you hover over `store.dispatch` or `AppDispatch`, what is the final TS type that's shown for that?

Comment: @markerikson Thanks for commenting!
For store.dispatch it says ```(property) EnhancedStore<{ mySlice: mySlice; }, AnyAction, MiddlewareArray<any>>.dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>```
For AppDispatch, it says ```type AppDispatch = Dispatch<AnyAction>```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow having the LogRocket middleware included in there is wiping out the actual correct type inference for the `middleware` option, and that means that the `AppDispatch` type does not know that the thunk middleware has been included.  Because of that, it's saying "you can't dispatch a thunk".

FWIW, we actually have LogRocket in our own codebase.  It looks like I had to cast `reduxMiddleware` to get it to work correctly.

Try adding `import type { Middleware } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"`, and then cast `LogRocket.reduxMiddleware() as Middleware` and see what happens.